# No such file or directory" [Errno 2] No such file or directory with flask

Tags: python, http, flask

I am learning Flask and am attempting to work through the uploading files.

> **I get the following [Errno 2] No such file or directory with flask.**

[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwamd.png)

How can I tell Flask to look in the right place?

See my **app.html**

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify, Flask, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app
import random
import os
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np



@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
     return render_template('index.html', title='Home')




@app.route('/upload.php', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      model= ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
      img = image.load_img(f.filename)
      preds = model.predict(img)
      return render_template('uploaded.html',  predictions=preds_decoded)



@app.route('/map')
def map():
    return render_template('map.html', title='Map')


@app.route('/map/refresh', methods=['POST'])
def map_refresh():
    points = [(random.uniform(48.8434100, 48.8634100),
               random.uniform(2.3388000, 2.3588000))
              for _ in range(random.randint(2, 9))]
    return jsonify({'points': points})


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', title='Contact')
```

I defined my UPLOADED_FOLDER in my **config.py**

/Users/name/Desktop/flaskSaaS-master/app/forms

my **config.py**

```
import logging

from app.config_common import *
from flask import Flask
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension


app = Flask(__name__)

# the toolbar is only enabled in debug mode:
app.debug = True

    # set a 'SECRET_KEY' to enable the Flask session cookies app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'houdini' app.config['DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS'] = False toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

    # DEBUG can only be set to True in a development environment for security reasons DEBUG = True

    # Secret key for generating tokens SECRET_KEY = 'houdini'

    # Admin credentials ADMIN_CREDENTIALS = ('admin', 'pa$$word')

    # Database choice SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///app.db' SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True

    # Configuration of a Gmail account for sending mails MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com' MAIL_PORT = 465 MAIL_USE_TLS = False MAIL_USE_SSL = True MAIL_USERNAME = 'flask.boilerplate' MAIL_PASSWORD
    = 'flaskboilerplate123' ADMINS = ['flask.boilerplate@gmail.com']

    # Number of times a password is hashed BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 12

    LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG LOG_FILENAME = 'activity.log' LOG_MAXBYTES = 1024 LOG_BACKUPS = 2


    UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/Users/name/Desktop/flaskSaaS-master/app/forms'
```

**Debug:**

```
* Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 127-013-508
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 20:48:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 20:48:36] "GET /_debug_toolbar/static/css/toolbar.css?0.5076085944288159 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 20:49:04] "POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 125, in dispatch_request
    return view_func(**req.view_args)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/cProfile.py", line 109, in runcall
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/lorenzocastagno/Desktop/flaskSaaS-master/app/views/main.py", line 27, in upload
    img = image.load_img(f.filename)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 110, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(path)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2770, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mmm.jpg'
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 20:49:04] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 20:49:04] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 20:49:04] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 20:49:04] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2019 20:49:04] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit your question to include the full error traceback message, as @furas commented.

Comment: Hi @fFuras  sorry.. now the trace is included...thanks for the corrections

Comment: @John  now the trace is included...thanks for the corrections

Comment: You probably want to use the full pathname to the image file, not just the bare filename, when calling `load_img()`.  Try this: `load_img(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, f.filename))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `img = image.load_img(f.filename)`

The `load_img` will try to read the file from the server. But in your case the file is not present in the file system of the server and is available in the `request.files`

In order to solve this, first you need to [write the file](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) present in `request.files` to some location and then use that location to load the file